# multiple CNAME for separate folders on github static pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I couldn't find the proper answer to this one. I have my personal `jekyll` blog on github. Now i created a static website for one of my js library and added it inside a folder using git submodule. The application works completely fine.

The problem is that for the project i want to use a domain of [js.org](https://github.com/js-org/dns.js.org) project . For project only and not my blog part.

Would adding a `CNAME` file inside the submodule folder work ? because i am using my personal domain currently for the blog part ?

Comment: @SLaks the ip of github would be configured on both domain names. Github uses repo as webroot and CNAME for host. Basically what i am asking is if there was another CNAME file inside one of its folder, would it consider it webroot for that host ?

Comment: Here is the best example of what i wanted weizhenye.github.io and weizhenye.github.io/ASS both open separate domains exactly how i want it to be